# Set background based on SPAN contents

Tags: jquery

I need to set a different background image dependant on the contents of a SPAN:

```
<div class="replies">
<span>2</span>
</div>
```

If SPAN = 1 background-image: url('reply.png') no-repeat;

If SPAN = 'anything other than 1' background-image: url('replies.png') no-repeat;

Can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: As different answers has interpreted this differently... The background image of what? The page? The div element?

Comment: your question, `Can this be done in jQuery?` : My answer, `YES!`

Comment: @Reigel: Completely correct, but rather useless. ;) You have to think beyond the actual questions that is posed, some even forget to ask an actual question... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can loop through the elements, get the span inside and check the contents:

```
$(function(){
  $('.replies').each(function(){
    var img = 'replies.png';
    if ($(this).find('span').text() == '1') {
      img = 'reply.png';
    }
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ') no-repeat');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

should be easy going

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var span = $('.replies').find('span').text();
    if(span === '1')
       $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'reply.png\') no-repeat');
    else
       $(this).css('background-image', 'url(\'replies.png\') no-repeat');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take

`$("div.replies > span").text()` and check that aginst "1"

```
var spanText = $("div.replies > span").text();

if ( spanText === "1" )
{
    // change bg image
}
else
{
    // another bg image
}
```